# Xamarin Android : How to change the position of an item on the contextual action mode

Tags: xamarin.android

I've implemented a recyclerview and inserted in it a contextual action mode.

In the action mode I removed the back button and inserted a checkbox. I want to change the position of the checkbox to be in the beginning of the contextual action mode and move the title of contextual action mode to the center.

How can I change the position of these two items?

I wish to achieve like the image below:

[image]

My contextual action mode:

```
public class MyActionMode : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
{
    private bool ischeck = false;
    private Context mContext;
    public static RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private int currentPosition;
    private Button button;
    private Button buttonTitle;
    private Button buttonCheckbox;
    public View mView;
    private List<Email> mEmails;

    public MyActionMode(Activity mActivity, Context context)
    {

    }

    public MyActionMode(Context context, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, int position, View v, List<Email> Emails)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mAdapter = adapter;
        currentPosition = position;
        mView = v;
        mEmails = Emails;
    }


    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.itemTwoId:
                // do Update
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.itemOneId:
                // do Update
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        mode.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.ContextualMenu, menu);


        button = (Button)menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.itemTwoId).ActionView;
        button.Background = null;
        button.TranslationX = 100;
        var draw = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(mContext, Resource.Drawable.three_dots);
        button.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(draw, null, null, null);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            PopupMenu menu1 = new PopupMenu(mContext, button);
            menu1.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popup_menu);
            menu1.Show();
        };

        buttonCheckbox = (Button)menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.itemOneId).ActionView;
        buttonCheckbox.Text = "Todos";
        buttonCheckbox.TranslationY = -30;
        buttonCheckbox.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        buttonCheckbox.Click += delegate


        {
            if (ischeck)
            {
                RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
                mAdapter.removeSelection();
                ischeck = false;
            }
            else
            {
                RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
                mAdapter.checkall();
                ischeck = true;
            }
        };
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
        mAdapter.removeSelection();
        mode.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My RecyclerView Adapter:

```
 public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, View.IOnClickListener, View.IOnLongClickListener
{
    private View view;
    private Boolean isSelected = false;

    public Boolean IsSelected()
    {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Boolean selected)
    {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public static RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    public static bool isActionMode = true;
    private int viewType;
    private ViewGroup parent;
    public static bool unselect = false;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private MyActionMode mActionMode;
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    private List<Email> mEmails;
    private Context context;
    private View p;
    private ActionMode mode;
    public static bool count = false;
    public static int CountAuxiliar = 0;
    private MyActionMode myActionMode;

    public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Context context)
    {
        mEmails = emails;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Activity activity)
    {
        mEmails = emails;
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> mEmails, MyActionMode myActionMode)
    {
        this.mEmails = mEmails;
        this.myActionMode = myActionMode;
    }

    public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public View mMainView { get; set; }
        public TextView mName { get; set; }
        public TextView mSubject { get; set; }
        public TextView mMessage { get; set; }

        public MyView(View view) : base(view)
        {
            mMainView = view;
        }

    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return mEmails.Count; }
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
        View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder vh = new RecyclerViewHolder(row);
        return vh;
    }
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        RecyclerViewHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
        myHolder.cbx.Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
        myHolder.cbx.Checked = mEmails[position].IsSelected();


        myHolder.mName.Text = mEmails[position].Name;
        myHolder.mSubject.Text = mEmails[position].Subject;
        myHolder.mMessage.Text = mEmails[position].Message;


        myHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
        myHolder.ItemView.Tag = position;
        myHolder.ItemView.SetOnClickListener(this);
        myHolder.ItemView.SetOnLongClickListener(this);

    }

    void View.IOnClickListener.OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (CountAuxiliar > 0 && mode != null)
        {
            int position = (int)v.Tag;
            mEmails[position].setSelected(!mEmails[position].IsSelected());
            v.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
            v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
            if (mEmails[position].IsSelected())
            {
                CountAuxiliar++;
            }
            else
            {
                CountAuxiliar--;
            }
            mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionados";
            Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Click : " + CountAuxiliar + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        if (CountAuxiliar < 1 && count == true)
        {
            count = false;
            mode.Finish();
            MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            MainActivity.floatinactionbutton1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
    }
    public void removeSelection()
    {
        if (mEmails != null)
        {
            foreach (Email email in mEmails)
            {
                email.setSelected(false);

            }
        }
        MyActionMode.mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        CountAuxiliar = 0;
        count = false;
        MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        MainActivity.floatinactionbutton1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

    }

    public void checkall()
    {
        if (mEmails != null)
        {
            foreach (Email email in mEmails)
            {
                email.setSelected(true);

            }
        }
        MyActionMode.mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public bool OnLongClick(View v)
    {

        if (CountAuxiliar < 1)
        {
            CountAuxiliar = 1;
            count = true;
            int position = (int)v.Tag;
            mEmails[position].setSelected(!mEmails[position].IsSelected());
            v.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
            MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            MainActivity.floatinactionbutton1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
            mActionMode = new MyActionMode(mActivity, this, position, v, mEmails);
            mode = mActivity.StartActionMode(mActionMode);
            mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionado";
            count = true;

            Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Long Click : " + mEmails[position].IsSelected() + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The part of the code I am inserting the contextual action mode title:

```
 if (mEmails[position].IsSelected())
            {
                CountAuxiliar++;
            }
            else
            {
                CountAuxiliar--;
            }
            mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionados";
```

Comment: BTW, how do you put a checkBox on the left in contextual action mode while the other two menus on the right？ Could you please post some code snippet?

Comment: The checkbox be on the leftside wasnt intentional , when i declared the checkbox item on the xml it stayed on the left side

Comment: You can try: `ActionMode.setCustomView( )` to custom ActionMode.

Comment: I ve tried ActionMode.setCustomView( )  but when i declare:

Comment: mode.CustomView.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

Comment: The result is null and the app crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem creating a second toolbar and using as a contextual action mode

the main ativity axml:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
            android:background="#E8E8E8"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"  
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <CheckedTextView
                android:text="Todos"
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:layout_width="30sp"
                android:layout_height="30sp"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:clickable ="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Title"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Teste"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:textSize="25sp"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/menubutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="345sp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Are you replacing the contextual action mode with the ToolBar?

Comment: Yes, i created a toolbar to  be a contextual action  mode in this toolbar i can position elements  Where i need. This toolbar stays hided and when i long click a recyclerview item the toolbar is shown

Comment: Wow, perfect. Congrats.